# special characters in bash script

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I have a bash script that has the following line in it

```
mysql -uusername -ppassword -e 'UPDATE \'table-name.config\' SET value=1234567890 WHERE action_code=102 AND name=\'last_updated_date\';'
```

but I get

```
./hybrid_telepath/install: line 856: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
./hybrid_telepath/install: line 872: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

clearly I have a problem with my characters and dont close the line well.

Any idea how to do it in bash?

If I change it to

```
mysql -uusername -ppassword -e "UPDATE `table-name`.`config` SET value=1312626266 WHERE action_code=102 AND name='last_updated_date';"
```

I get

```
line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET value=1312626266 WHERE action_code=102 AND name=last_updated_date' at line 1
```

Thanks

Comment: maybe you need to double-escape? `... UPDATE \\'table....`?

Comment: Tried that..doesn't work :-(

Comment: What's with this part and the multiple backquotes: \`table-name\`.\`config\`? Why not leave it as 'table-name.config'?

Comment: do not use back-quotes at all ? use single quotes instead ?

Answer (score 2):

Escape sequences don't work inside single quotes. Use double quotes for your outer-most quotes, and then you don't need to escape the single quotes within:

```
mysql -uusername -ppassword -e "UPDATE 'table-name.config' SET value=1234567890 WHERE action_code=102 AND name='last_updated_date';"
```

Comment: another way :    'UPDATE'\''table-name.conf'\'' ......' (ie, inside `'` , insert a single quote by :   `'  \'  '` (in the example it looks like a double quote as both single quote are so close) ... ugly, but keeps the whiole thing in single quotes, therefore escaping most special characters ($, etc) )

Comment: I tried what you said but I get another issue..I updated my question

Comment: Back-quotes inside double quotes execute the shell 'command' inside the back-quotes.  You have to escape those if the query is in double quotes.  Alternatively, keep your single quotes, but when you need a single quote in the query string, use the sequence `'\''`.  The first quote finishes the current single-quoted string; the backslash single quote embeds a single quote; the final single quote resumes a single-quoted string.

Answer (score 1):

The previous poster is correct.  In addition to the suggestion that you use double quotes, you might want to start building your queryString separately.  This practice will serve you well as you get better at scripting (and, hopefully, move-on-to something like Python).  It's also a bad practice to hard-code your database credentials in your script.  Please note that you can define these values elsewhere (i.e., in another script) and then just source that script.  This makes your code modular.  Even better, write functions, source 'em, and reuse.  Here's an example:

```
#!/bin/bash
. /etc/myDbCreds

myQuery="select * from foo where bar ='snafu';"

mysql -u $myUser -p${myPass} -e $myQuery
```

Comment: You need to enclose the query in double quotes, don't you?  I'd enclose all the variables reference in the command line in double quotes, in fact.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
mysql -uusername -ppassword -e "UPDATE \'table-name.config\' SET value=1234567890 WHERE action_code=102 AND name=\'last_updated_date\';"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar question about -e "" of mysql cmd.

This looks normal:

```
$ mysql -h vip0 -u root -pqwerty -e "show databases;" 
+--------------------+ 
| Database           | 
+--------------------+ 
| information_schema | 
| mysql              | 
| performance_schema | 
+--------------------+
```

But if I want to execute it via ssh, it does not work:

```
$ ssh g1 --  mysql -hvip0 -uroot -pqwerty -e "show databases;" 
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'databases'
```

As tested, it seems I need to escape the space:

```
$ ssh g1 --  mysql -hvip0 -uroot -pqwerty -e "show\ databases;" 
Database 
information_schema 
mysql 
performance_schema
```

But I don't understand why...